# How to reorder bootstrap cols on mobile?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, less

I have 4 cols as follows on desktop, and I would like them to reorder in such a way that it appears as depicted below on mobile.
Do I need custom css for this?

(I Cannot post images yet, so here is the link to the image:)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0gUZ.jpg

I have tried keeping them in parent cols of two in each, but to no-avail.
I am a backend guy, so I am not too familiar with frontend stuff.

Current HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div>B</div>
    <div>D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like it to behave as I have depicted in the image.

How do I go about doing this? I do not want to resort to JavaScript. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `<div class="col-md-6 col-12">` should do it -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

If you play with your html structure then no need to have custom css. 
Just update classes and content in your code as follows:

````
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div  class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">A</div>
        <div  class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">B</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">C</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">D</div>
     </div>
</div>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code , bootstrap only

```
<section>
    <div class="container my-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">c</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">d</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
```